# SKSpritenodes stop moving when given physics body

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

When i give two nodes in my game a physics body, they stop doing what i want them to do. I have two bars at the bottom of the scene,one starts on the left, and the other is on the right, and they continuously go to meet at the middle then move back to there starting spot, like a floor opening up. Without a physics body, they do exactly this, but when i give them a physics body,when they both meet in the middle, they stop there and don't move back out.

Here are the bars:

```
    bar.position = CGPoint(x:-self.size.width * 0.2, y:(self.size.height * 0.03));
    bar.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: text, size: text.size())
    bar.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.bar
    bar.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.ball
    bar.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.bar
    self.addChild(bar)
    bar1.position = CGPoint(x:self.size.width * 1.2, y:(self.size.height * 0.03));
    bar1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: text, size: text.size())
    bar1.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.bar
    bar1.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.ball
    bar1.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.bar
    self.addChild(bar1)
```

And this is how they move. This is in the update method:

```
if (bar.position.x == -self.size.width * 0.2)
    {
        let move = SKAction.moveToX(self.size.width * 0.012, duration: 1);
        bar.runAction(move);
    } else if (bar.position.x == self.size.width * 0.012) {
        let move = SKAction.moveToX(-self.size.width * 0.2, duration: 1)
        bar.runAction(move)
    }
    if (bar1.position.x == self.size.width * 1.2)
    {
        let move = SKAction.moveToX(self.size.width * 0.988, duration: 1);
        bar1.runAction(move);
    } else if (bar1.position.x == self.size.width * 0.988) {
        let move = SKAction.moveToX(self.size.width * 1.2, duration: 1)
        bar1.runAction(move)
    }
```

What could be causing them to stick together at the middle when i give them a physics body.

Comment: This is a shot in the dark but try to find the exact point that the bars stop at. You can find the position they get stuck by putting this in the update function, `println(bar.position.x)` or `println(bar1.position.x)` . Then, put these positions in your if statements to make sure that the bars will move when they are supposed to.

Comment: @AidanKaiser Does the way I have the collision bitmask set up mean that the bars wont interact with each other? I've been printing its x location and I'm seeing that its not going to where its suppose to, and i think its because the other bar is stopping it.

Comment: Physics bodies automatically collide with one another. Collision bitmasks are for detecting the collision and doing something when the two bodies collide. Your physics bodies are the exact size as the original node correct?